# Pause message consumption and resume after time interval

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We are using spring-cloud-stream to work with kafka. And I need to add some interval between getting data by consumer from single topic.
batch-node is already set as true , also fetch-max-wait, fetch-min-size, max-poll-records are already tuned.

Should I do something with idleEventInterval, or it's wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pause/resume the container as needed (avoiding a rebalance).

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding_visualization_control

> Since version 3.1 we expose `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingsLifecycleController` which is registered as bean and once injected could be used to control the lifecycle of individual bindings

If you only want to delay for a short time, you can set the container's `idleBetweenPolls` property, using a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean.